# What does Kotlin's type reification make possible that is not possible in Java or Scala?

Tags: java, scala, generics, types, kotlin

I am most familiar with Java type erasure (with all its issues and benefits). I have some limited exposure to the expanded possibilities with Kotlin's type system, but I don't have a clear understanding of how type reification works on an erasure-oriented JVM. What is type reification, how does Kotlin make it possible on the JVM, and how does this differ from Java's type erasure and Scala's sophisticated type system?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### What is reification?

Type reification is one of Kotlin's tricks. It happens only in inlined generic functions, if you declare the generic parameter as `reified`.

Since it's inlined, the generic parameter can be a concrete `class`, instead of just a compile-time type information.
You can do something impossible in Java like:

### instanceof

You can now use `instanceof`s (in Kotlin, `is`s):

```
inline fun <reified T> f(a: Any) {
    if (a is T) println("Hi!")
}
```

This is obviously impossible in Java.

### reflection

You're possible to get the java `java.lang.Class<T>` instance from the generic parameter now.

```
inline fun <reified T> f(a: Any) {
    println("Hey! my class is ${T::class.java}!")
    if (a.javaClass == T::class.java) println("Hi!")
}
```

Also, `KClass` as well:

```
inline fun <reified T> f(a: Any) {
    println("KClass: ${T::class}")
}
```

You can create instances with the empty constructor:

```
inline fun <reified T> f(a: Any) {
    val o: T = T::class.java.newInstance()
}
```

### calling other reifieds

Only `reified` generic parameter is possible to be passed to other `reified` functions.

```
inline fun <reified T> f(a: Any) {
    g<T>(a)
}

inline fun <reified T> g(a: Any) {
    if (a is T) println("Bingo!")
}
```

This is impossible in Kotlin:

```
inline fun <reified T> f(a: Any) {
}

fun <T> g(a: Any) {
    f<T>(a) // error
}
```

### shortcomings (edited)

<del>If you use other languages to invoke a `reified` inline function in Kotlin, the function parameter will be `java.lang.Object`.</del>

You can't use other languages to invoke a `reified` function.

Like, if we have a reified function in `A.kt`:

```
inline fun <reified T> f(a: T) = println(T::class.java)
```

And get it using reflection (it will be compiled as private):

```
Method method = AKt.class.getDeclaredMethod("f", Object.class);
```

This code will successfully run without exceptions.
But you can't invoke it (I didn't read the generated bytecode carefully, sorry) due to it's implementation:

```
private static final void f(Object a) {
  Intrinsics.reifiedOperationMarker(4, "T"); // I didn't see
  // the implementation of this line, so I thought it's
  // possible to call it in other languages
  Class var2 = Object.class;
  System.out.println(var2);
}
```

Look at the comment. And look at the definition of `reifiedOperationMarker`:

```
public static void reifiedOperationMarker(int id, String typeParameterIdentifier) {
    throwUndefinedForReified();
}
```

And it will throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Conclusion: `reified` can only be used in Kotlin.

### about scala

It's really difficult to say whether Kotlin or Scala is better, because Scala's has more ways to get type information at runtime.

Alexey Romanov said that Scala can but Kotlin can't:

> using ClassTags in a recursive function

I think this can be solved by using functions inside functions:

```
inline fun <reified T> g(a: Any): Int {
  var recur: ((Any) -> T)? = null
  recur = { recur!!.invoke(it) as T } // use T is possible here
  return recur(a)
}
```

Note that this is only an example that syntactically correct.
It's infinite loop and unnecessary cast, of course.

He also said:

> storing them in collections and using them to call ClassTag-using functions later.

This is a true problem, because this needs `noinline` lambdas, while Kotlin's `reified` is based on inline.

Comment: "Scala supports type fields, it solves this problem by reflection." `type` fields aren't relevant to this question and it doesn't solve this problem by reflection.

Comment: "If you use other languages to invoke a reified inline function " - does it work? Could you provide an example?

Comment: Write a Kotlin inline function, and call it in Java. You'll see. I'll add an exmaple..

Comment: And, you need reflection. Because they're compiled to be private.

Comment: Wait. I didn't actually invoked it before (I just read the generated code carelessly), and I realized it's impossible to invoke it in Java/Scala. See the update. @voddan

Answer (score 3):

When Kotlin inlines a generic function, it naturally substitutes the type parameters by the type it was called with. E.g. with `inline fun <T> foo(x: T) = ...`

```
foo(File("."))
```

becomes

```
val x = File(".")
// body of foo with File used everywhere T was
```

What `reified` does is just to allow using operations in body of `foo` which will only make sense *after* this substitution but are illegal for non-`reified` type parameters, such as `T::class`.

The relevant Scala feature is `ClassTag`/`TypeTag`, not the "sophisticated type system". Effectively, it automates passing the `Class<T>` (or `TypeToken<T>`) as an argument, which can be done manually in Java and often is. Note that this is a *completely* different approach than `reified`.

I don't think there's anything which `reified` does which isn't possible in Scala, but the advantage of the Kotlin approach is more natural syntax: e.g. in in Scala you can't just write `classOf[T]` in a `ClassTag`-using method like you would `classOf[File]`.

OTOH, Scala allows things which aren't possible with `reified`, e.g.:

1. using `ClassTag`s in a recursive function
2. storing them in collections and using them to call `ClassTag`-using functions later.